# 0xc000007b error in C# application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This question may be asked so many times. I searched for the solution too much. I got a solution (although that didn't work) to replace some .dll files.

Actually I made an application in Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit, Visual Studio 2010, target Framework 3.5 with MS Access 2007 Database (Platform target `x86`). Then I tried to run this application (.exe file) on another machine having Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit. But the error appeared.

As I got solution to replace those 5 dll files in `\Windows\SYSWOW64` folder, but cannot find this folder on 32 machine. Even though I replaced/copied those 5 dlls to `System32` folder. But the same error.

I also installed framework 4.0 on the target machine. But the same error.

Now how to resolve this error? Thanks...

Comment: have you tried to build for x86?

Comment: I guess you have compiled for x64 - you need to compile for x86

Comment: Application is compiled for x86. Forgot to mention in question.

Comment: .NET framework 4.0 *doesn't contain 3.5*. You have to install 3.5. Replacing random files in `System32` is a great way to cause major trouble (thankfully, Windows will just replace them back). You have to compile your application *and all your references* as 32-bit - that includes those Access interop libraries. Non-.NET DLLs are most likely at fault (do you use P/Invoke?). And of course, is Access even installed on the target computer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems makes this happen (in my case)...

1. Most important to check for the `VIRUSES`;
2. Application is compiled in `x64` and running on `x86` platform;
3. If any `dll`, compiled in `x64` platform, added to the `x86` application;

These are some of those problems gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

Syswow64 is a folder just for 64 bit versions of Windows, where it stores files for 32 bit programs. It shouldn't exist on 32 bit Windows.

Try compiling for 32 bit Windows, then running on the other computer.

Comment: I made the whole application on 32 bit win 7 home basic. And tried to run it on client's pc,  same error. I also installed visual c++ redistributable 2008 on client's pc, SAME ERROR.

Comment: I found some solutions for the error. They are 1. To compile whole application on 32 bit os. 2. 64 bit dlls can make trouble.  3. Icons for the application can make trouble.  Done all of them,  but same error. Tired of this.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change system target. On menu Build -> Configuration Manager, you can change the platform to x86 instead of x64.

Comment: Why the answer was negativated?? I post before he comments that the app is compiled to x86.

Comment: And yet, after he posted that the application is built for x86, you still leave the answer up?

Comment: Do i need to delete the answer?